# Should we use Java code to select data or use stored procedure in this particular case?

Tags: java, sql, database, stored-procedures

Let's see this Java code:

```
// Code to connect DB
try {
       while (rs!=null){

        String sql="SELECT c1 FROM tbl WHERE c1 like ?";

        preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, "%test%");

        ResultSet rs = preparedStmt.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            String c1 = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(c1);
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            System.out.println ("SQL Exception:  " + ex.getMessage ());
            ex = ex.getNextException ();
        }
} catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
        System.out.println("***ERROR-->" + e.toString());   
}
```

Note: the loop can have 4 or 5 loops

The second solution is to use DB stored procedure, but I don't know how to write it & I don't want to remember all the stored procedures (ie I have to reimport the stored procedure if I use new DB) when I deploy my app.

But I am not sure the performance of my app got influenced or not since I sent many query to DB via a loop like that.

If you have any experience in this kind of situation, please share with me.

Comment: Where do you manipulate the data exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stored procedures are for doing things that are very complicated and cannot be accomplished with one query. Instead of doing multiple queries and using e.g. Java to get the final result, you make a stored procedure to allow you to do the processing DB side and only return the results to the Java client.

This has the advantage of:

- Less back and forth network overhead
- Executing multiple SQL queries

And the disadvantage of:

- Having to write a stored procedure which is something new entirely
- More processing taking place server side (though this is debatable as multiple queries also consume resources).

For a query as simple as that, it is hands down ONE SQL query, so no stored procedure makes sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the outer loop is also influenced from some database query. In this case you do however not need a stored procedure, you can simple write one SQL statement combining the outer and inner SQL statement, most probably through some table join. Since the outer query is not posted I can however only guess.

In gerneral, all other things equal, having one "big" SQL statement and a sufficiently indexed database will be quicker, since:

- The network delays are reduced to one query
- The database can derive a cleaver execution plan, thus reduce the amount of data earlier
- Less data is transfered over the network

However, if the compuation of the query is complex and your database is the bottleneck it might be smart to shift these heavy tasks to multiple application servers.